# How do I use the NumPy array returned from sounddevice Stream class to perform additional processing?

Tags: python, numpy, portaudio

I am using a python library [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/) for some audio processing. When I use the Stream class to pass the input data collected from input device (mic) through to the output, the callback function has a NumPy array that represents the sound data:

```
def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    outdata[:] = indata
```

**indata** is a NumPy array that contains arrays of floats. What do these floats represent? How can I perform time stretching or pitch shifting on this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a warning: If you want efficient and reliable realtime audio processing, Python is probably not a very good choice (because it's an interpreted language, it uses garbage collection and of course because of the infamous GIL).

If you want to use Python anyway, there are a few libraries for realtime audio signal processing; [pyo](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/) and [LibROSA](http://bmcfee.github.io/librosa/) come to mind, more can be found at the [PythonInMusic wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic).

Now to answer your actual question: The floating point values (by default `float32`) in `indata` are amplitude values that represent sound pressure.
You can also think of it as voltage, if that helps.

Note that the values coming from the sound card are limited to a range from `-1.0` to `+1.0`. When you write your output signal(s) to `outdata`, you have to take care that they are also limited to this range, otherwise you will hear ugly distortions.

The `indata` and `outdata` arrays are 2-dimensional, where the columns represent the audio channels. Each row represents one time instance.

You might also want to read my little [page about creating simple audio signals with Python](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/simple-signals.ipynb).

The actual algorithms for time stretching/pitch shifting are off-topic here, if you need help you can ask at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This answer might not be accurate anymore in regards to the range. I just recorded some data with sd.rec (44.1khz, float32, 2 channels) and what I get is a numpy array of dtype np.float32 but with min, max values around -/+ 1.44.

Comment: @Toby I think you are right, the limitation from `-1.0` to `+1.0` is not true for all systems, see also https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/23 (which is talking about the *output range*, not the *input range*). Do you happen to use a Mac? If you have any more details, please let us know!